# Monitor doesn't properly display the supported resolution

Tags: linux, debian, display, resolution

So, bit of background. I am using the [FLATRON L192WS monitor](http://www.afterdawn.com/products/product_details.cfm/5743/lg_l192ws) on a system running [Debian Squeeze.](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/) Essentially what happened is that when I set the resolustion to the max supported (1440x900), I keep having a black dead pixel space in the right and bottom sides of the screen. [image: As you can see in this image.]

As a result I can't see the top bar and left bar of my screen, which is messed up. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this monitor is connected by analog cable, that uses blue connectors with (i think) 15 pins, it is normal for it to need adjustment. It's menu should include an option for `Auto-Adjustment`. If that doesn't work, try manual.

If it is connected through digital cable (DVI or HDMI or DP) - this would not be normal, and i can't think of a way to remedy your problem.

Comment: sweet, thanks, never thought it was a hardware problem.. Accepted