# Screen resolution cannot be set properly

Tags: windows-7, display, amd-catalyst

A friend of mine bought a new machine for his parents. It is runnning Windows 7 and has an AMD APU. The monitor **only has an [analogue connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector)**.
If I try to set the resolution of the monitor to the native 1920x1080, the picture is too big, meaning neither edge of the screen is visible. ([just like this question on the board](https://superuser.com/questions/543677/monitor-doesnt-properly-display-the-supported-resolution)) The monitor is from Samsung, a SyncMaster SA300, it has **no settings for screen size**, just position. "Auto adjustment" does not help.

If I open the Catalyst Control Center, and set the frequency to 30 Hz, the picture size is perfect, but the characters are still blurry, and the image vibrates visibly.
The best setting currently is 1600x1200 at 60Hz. The picture is quite sharp, but everything is distorted, as we view a 4:3 image stretched to a 19:9 display. 
All I could find on the forums is that I should turn off `Overscan`, but I was not able to find it in the Catalyst Control Center.

**Any suggestions?**